# Como limitar IPs que podem conetar remotamente ao mysql?

Tags: mysql, centos

Tenho um servidor centos 7 com MySQL 5.6 instalado, consigo controlar os privilégios de cada usuário/host com o GRANT.
Mas minha dúvida é como permitir que somente alguns IPs conectem ao banco.
 Atualmente qualquer IP pode conectar, mas só os que tem algum privilegio executam algo.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: seria isso util https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/whitelist-source-ip-addresses-in-centos-7

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa fazer REVOKE, veja mais detalhes no link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/revoke.html

`REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* FROM 'jane'@'56.44.3.24';`

Comment: Sim, já tentei com o REVOKE, mas a conexão ainda é permitida.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver excluindo a linha da tabela mysql.user em que o host='%' e o usuário='usuario'.
Não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas funcionou, agora só conectam os usuários/hosts que tem algum privilégio.